# railway cross level detection using image processing technique

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

[railway track detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/difnV.jpg)

how can I check this railway cross level are in  same level or not using image processing technique ?

Need to check is there any distance measuring algorithm to calculate the railway cross level detection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic]